# Using VBA, I'm trying to round all the values in column O to the nearest 25 (integer). Not getting any errors but it's just not working

Tags: excel, vba

Column O has a list of prices. I want to round them all to the nearest 25 (integer) using the M Round function. I need it automated via VBA.

Tried with and without End if- neither work. The latter gives me an error.

Here's the code i've been using:

```
Sub MRound2()

    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, A As Range, LastRow As Long
    Dim dblMRound As Double
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prices").Range("O4:O" & LastRow)
    
    For Each cell In rng
    
    dblMRound = WorksheetFunction.MRound(Arg1:=O4, Arg2:=25)
        
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `cell.value= WorksheetFunction.MRound(Arg1:=cell.value, Arg2:=25)`

Comment: BTW you will also want to make sure you are looking at the correct sheet when doing the last row: `LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prices").Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row`